# Motorcycle: Annoying brake disc rubbing. Can't understand why

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, disk-brakes

My bike is two months old. After about 1000 km's. I noticed rubbing on front disks. I think the left one making all sound. And the worse, this rubbing shaking handlebar after about 95 kmph and all vehicle after about 120 kmph. It is not a constant rubbing. It is only rubbing at a point of a spin of wheel. So first, I thought my disks are warped. But two disks and pads are changed. And it's still rubbing. Only shakes and sounds a bit less than before. May be %30 less. So the situation is very very strange. If I don't use the bike 1-2 days, I can't hear the sound clearly before first front braking. Then annoying thing is back... We lifted front wheel and while turning it it is rubbing at a point of every spin.

It makes it difficult to solve the problem of having rubbing not constant but with intervals

I think my service can't detect the cause of problem and I want to suggest them something to look at. Can calipers cause this?  Do you have any ideas?

**Bike and Brake Specs:**

Benelli TRK 502

> Front Brake:
>   Twin semi floating disk ø320 mm with 4 pistons caliper and ABS
>
> Rear Brake:
>   Single disc ø260 mm with single piston calliper and ABS

Comment: Do you have access to a dial indicator?  Can you measure runout on surface of brake rotor?

Comment: @zipzit I can only ask if my local service had it but really I don't think so.

Comment: Is the pad "returning" properly? Or the piston / caliper sticking?

Comment: @SolarMike Is there a way to observe this? Without disassemble brakes? I am suspecting about left caliper.

Comment: Lift the wheel off the ground and then spin the wheel - operate the brakes and see...

Comment: @SolarMike Tried that. The wheel spins and rubbing continues. When spinned and released, wheel stops earlier than normal.

Comment: Please provide some more information on your bike and brake setup. Is the caliper of the sliding type or opposing piston type? is the disk floating or fixed? Make and model please...

Comment: @r.anderson Added information to question.

Comment: Personally, if the bike is two months old, I would take it back and make them fix it under warranty. If they are unable to, have them give you another bike. You should not have to pay for a new bike that is defective.

Comment: @CharlieRB After changing discs and pads, they're can't notice sound and shaking. Actually I know they don't want to... So I am forcing them now. After all I'll contact distributor and even head office if necessary.

Comment: Had same type of rubbing and annoying sound problem with my Motorcycle's back disc brakes. After a lot of research and repairs, i found it was just an improper bleeding, had some air in the system. i bleed it correctly and it's gone.

Comment: @devst3r How this can cause a rubbing issue? Like I said mine is rubbing with intervals not constant. Like a bent disc. But the disc is not bent all I know is this. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @gkon The sound comes in interval and at a certain point of contact only. i also thought my disc might be warped. but the problem was gone after bleeding.

Comment: Did you by any chance washed your bike right after an extensive brakes use???

Answer (score 0):

If the bike has not been raced or the discs overheated in any way then the discs 'runout' requires checking to make sure that it is not warped. If it is warped it requires changing, your bike is new and shouldn't have this issue so the bike/manufacturer warranty should cover it.

If the discs are found to be ok as far as runout goes then you may have a sticking caliper on one side. This too should not be occuring on a new bike so if it is sticking you want a new caliper under warranty.

Comment: There is no problem with warranty. Like I said discs and pads are replaced already and problem is not solved. I will force them to examine calipers asap.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a bent wheel or hub. A bike That new should be free of mechanical defect.  Assuming all else is in place with a thorough inspection.

Comment: I think a bent wheel would be easier to identify. And It's effects would be bigger. But really I didn't know that the hub could be bent. Will try to make them examine hub too.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the pistons I had the same issue with rear disc and caliper until it dumped it's oil due to poor oil seals.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the bike is shaking get the tyres checked out and have the wheels balanced. As this sounds like a balance issue. And not something to do with the disc rubbing. Tyres are are a good starting point for balance issues as tyres can be out of round or not be seated on the rim correctly giving speed balance/vibration issues.

Its not unusual for a bikes discs to rub slightly against the pads, If you spin almost all bikes front wheels you'll hear and feel sometimes the discs and pads contacting on each rotation. Any heavy binding when you spin the wheel needs investigating further though.

Answer (score 0):

Causes of brake rubbing in order of likelihood include;

- brake pads not moving freely in caliper/pad carrier or caliper sliders jamming.
- Caliper piston jamming.
- Blockage in master cylinder or master cylinder cap breather
- Brake pipe detioration causing a blockage in the hydraulic system.
- Other fault in the hydraulic system preventing releasing brake pressure when brake lever is released.

Prolonged brake rubbing can cause discs and pads to overheat and warp the disk.
Other less likely causes:

- Incorrectly mounted brake disk or caliper.
- Failing wheel bearings on the affected wheel.
- malfunction in ABS system (does it have ABS?)